# UIWebView and unload event

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm loading local html contents into a UIWebView.
The javascript code of the loaded contents includes this event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
  // do something here;
});
```

That javascript code it is only executed when (before) the UIWebView component is released (e.g. when navigating back to another view controller) but it is not executed when another page is loaded. For example:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){ document.location = "www.google.com"; });
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){ alert("bye bye"); });
```

If executing this piece of code in safari, when I click on the document, before navigating to google.com, it would display the alert box. If I run the same code in UIWebView, the unload listener it is not executed. However, If I delete the UIWebView, the code is then executed.

My need is to have the same as in Safari, that is the unload method to be executed also when navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thanks to LuisCien solution above (please vote his post if you like the solution)**, I managed to solve the issue by manually generating and dispatching the unload event from objective-c side. This does not require any modification on my client side code (javascript) that now behaves the same in UIWebView and any other web browser. Here is the piece of code to add to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var e=document.createEvent('Event'); e.initEvent('unload', true, true); window.dispatchEvent(e);"];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi @lviggiani. I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. I can see that you used the two methods that I suggested you in my answer (not hint). Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi LuisCien, the reason why I posted another solution (that is using your solution) is because yours it's only half of the solution of my problem: you wrote "Instead of using the unload listener you have in JavaScript..." but I have to keep my javascript as it is (including the unload listener) as that might run also in a common web browser. That's why I added the "server side code" for triggering the event, in case anyone else wants to see how to trigger that event from UIWebView. I've voted your answer and put credits to you in mine.

Comment: One thing to note..  webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest is also called if you load an iframe in your webpage.  So if you have a complicated webpage with multiple iframes, then you may throw this unnecessarily if you do not check the address of the request.

Comment: Thank you so much. Had problems with persisting SAP WebGUI sessions after WKWebView instance got dismissed, because SAP WebGUI closes session on the SAP NetWeaver server using code in window.unload event (and this wasn't called).

Answer (score 5):

I too have had problems in the past with JavaScript code that doesn't behave the same way in a desktop browser than in a `UIWebView`. I honestly don't know why it isn't working the way you want it to, but here I offer you a work around:

Instead of using the `unload` listener you have in JavaScript, try using `UIWebViewDelegate`'s method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. This method gets called whenever the user requests to load a new page (or content). 
If you then need to execute more JavaScript code you could use `UIWebView`'s method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, according to your hint, I execute the following javascript code in ebView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

var e = document.createEvent("Event");
e.initEvent("unload", true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(e);

This will trigger the window's unload listener so my javascript code (in the loaded html page) will work both in UIWebView and any other browser without modifications